# Removing the impact of an independent variable from a time series

Tags: time-series

My business problem statement: 
What would be the total impact on sales if we stop spending any money on advertising a product

Description and Context:

1. My company spends money in advertising to acquire users (called inorganic users).
2. But there are also those customers that research about our product and purchase them (I.e. Organic users, who irrespective of advertising are purchasing the products which owing to large sample space is assumed to be normally distributed)
3. Within Organic also there is a sub classification:
   3a. The ones that search by themselves and try our products 
   3b. Then there comes those sales which happen due to the inorganic customers referring the products (word of mouth, social media etc.) to the organic customers.
4. Therefore the total impact if we stop advertising would be loss of sales due to no inorganic customers and loss of organic customers due to referrals by inorganic customers.

My data problem:

I have the following data points:

1. Advertising spend
2. Total organic customers (including both the subsets mentioned in point 3 above)
3. Inorganic customers

How can I remove the effect of advertising to account for these referrals.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure that your problem is really a time-series one. I don't see time as a factor figuring in your description.

You need to set up a mathematical model, i.e. how you expect advertising to influence the number of customers. Let us use the following notation:

- $n$: the total number of customers;
- $n_I$: the number of inorganic customers;
- $n_{Oa}$: the number of "true" (type "a") organic customers;
- $n_{Ob}$: the number of type "b" organic customers;
- $a$: the amount spent on advertising.

By definition, $n = n_I + n_{Oa} + n_{Ob}$.

Now, your assumption is that:

- $n_I = f(a)$ (the number of inorganic customers is a function of advertising), and
- $n_{Ob} = g(n_I)$ (the number of organic "b" customers is another function of the number of inorganic customers). From above it follows: $n_{Ob} = g(f(a))$.

You need to make some assumption about the form of $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$. Probably the simplest (not necessarily correct) is that they are both linear:

- $f(a) = \beta_1 a$, and
- $g(n_I) = \beta_2 n_I = \beta_1 \beta_2 a$.

You can determine $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ by minimizing some (quadratic?) error between your model and your empirical data, e.g.:

$$
\min_\beta (n - n_{Oa} - \beta_1 a (1 + \beta_2))^2
$$

After determining the $\beta$'s, you simply set $a = 0$ and calculate the number of customers from the formulae above.

This basic idea$-$minimizing the error$-$ can also be used when your $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are not linear. For example, I'd assume that there is a saturation level, both for organic and inorganic customers, where spending more on advertising hardly brings any more customers. You can model that by some asymptotic function, e.g. $C_1 (1 - e^{\beta_1 a})$.

Comment: You are right, the time series actually isn't present in the problem inherently. What I presumed that n(oa) would follow a time series as that is purely based on randomness and dependent of time of the year and month. On the solution, the only problem I am facing is that I dont know n(oa) and hence I am not able to use the minimize function..Any thoughts there..

Comment: Can I use my marketing spend as an exogenous variable and then apply traditional time series model on my n(o)?...I came across this concept today..